# Smack 4 throws "SSLHandshakeException: ValidatorException: SunCertPathBuilderException" on connect

Tags: java, ssl, xmpp, smack

For integration testing of my xmpp stack I set up a vysper server (0.7) on localhost.
Now I want to connect to the server using smack-core and smack-tcp in version 4.0.2.

Problem:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Since the smack 4 api has changed a lot, the examples found so far can not be used anymore. 
Anyone tried this before?

Comment: Please note that Smack 4.0.3 is the current up-to-date version. But this isn't related to the Exception.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ... but 4.0.3 doesn't seem to be available on central: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.igniterealtime.smack/smack-core

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, 4.0.3 has been released to central and will be available soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `SSLHandashskeException` tells us that the SSL/TLS handshake has failed, which is because there was a `ValidatorException` that tells us that the "PKIX path building failed", because there was a `SunCertPathBuilderException` thrown because the Java API was "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

The Java API (ie. this is not done by Smack) could not build a valid certificate chain to the servers SSL/TLS certificate with the active SSLContext. That is why this exception is thrown. You need to provide either a valid certifcate (however that is defined by your currently used SSLContext) or tell Smack to use a SSLContext (`ConnectionConfiguration.setCustomSSLContext(SSLContext)`) that accepts your current server certificate

Comment: OK. I will give it a try (not sure I got everything, though :-)).

For my localhost i-test scenario, is there a way I could bypass all the certs and contexts?

Comment: Yes, but only do stuff like this if you aware about the security implications. You most likely want to simple disable security if you want to bypass all checks. Because the outcome is the same.

Comment: I cannot find how I disable security for vysper ... is it possible at all?

Comment: why not disable security in Smack?

Comment: I did, please see my updated question. If I do not call "server.setTLSCertificateInfo(certFile, "boguspw");", I get an NPE from vysper. BTW: thanks a lot for helping me out here!

Comment: Ok, since it appears that it's not possible to disable TSL in Vysper, I'll will give you a hint how to disable TLS verification in Smack. **DISCLAIMER: This will void all security guarantees TLS provides, you can also just send the data unencrypted.** See https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/b0825f73fdd084166e3b2d3067b39a0012011391/smack-core/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/util/TLSUtils.java#L89 and extract the method, since it's only available since Smack 4.1,

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did work! Could you update your answer so this workaround is easier to find by others?

Comment: No, I'm not keen on editing this info the answer and therefore increasing it's visibility. It's really just meant for quick tests. You should also drop this approach and write your own TrustManager that uses e.g. a pinning technique for your certificate. Really nobody is required or should use the accept all approach.

Comment: I get your point. I will dive into this again later.  For now i am happy that i can continue with my task (junit/itest my bots) without dealing with certs on localhost.

Comment: In order to create an SSLContext that accepts the current server certificate it is probably worth linking [Java-pinning](https://github.com/Flowdalic/java-pinning) that simplifies the task. Obviously this solution should *only* be used if you are in control of both ends of the TLS connection (see Java-pinning readme).

Comment: Unfortunately, Smack does not use custom SSL context with BOSH, it's just ignored. I wish they would start using it one day...

Comment: Did you notify the Smack developers about this? Was a Smack issue assigned?