# hava jabber-bot. XMPP over smack 4.2.0 with TLS

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I need to develop mini jabber-bot. I have an openfire server with only TLS connection rules. I used to smack 4.2.0 - last stable build from http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/ I try to connect but have an exception:
code:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setUsernameAndPassword("testjava", "12345678")
                .setServiceName(server)
                .setPort(5222)
                .setHost(server)                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .build();

        AbstractXMPPConnection conn2 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

        conn2.connect();
```

Log:

```
10:35:31 AM SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='***.pro' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='testjava@***.pro' xml:lang='en'>
10:35:31 AM RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="***.pro" id="xb9bamjxw" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
10:35:32 AM RECV (0): <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
10:35:32 AM SENT (0): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'></starttls>
10:35:32 AM RECV (0): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
Exception in thread "main" org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1010)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use Pidgin and have establish connect to the server. What  need I to add to my code to support TLS authenticat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smack 4 throws "SSLHandshakeException: ValidatorException: SunCertPathBuilderException" on connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495368/smack-4-throws-sslhandshakeexception-validatorexception-suncertpathbuilderexc)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your server doesn't have a 'valid' certificate.  Buy a valid certificate, or configure the library to allow 'untrusted' certificates.